# Programatically setting constraints between a ViewPager's item's widget and a widget of the layout that contains the ViewPager is impossible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-widget, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` that contains a `ViewPager` and another widget, we could call "A". I would want to add a constraint between one `ViewPager`'s widget (we could call "B") and "A". B is, of course, a widget that is contained, in reality, in a fragment (because `ViewPagers` work with fragments). Note that this fragment's layout is a `ConstraintLayout` too.

The fact is  that I can't do it using XML, if I have correctly understood what I read&tried.

So I have tried to do it programatically using this code:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = inflated.findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_constraint_layout);
constraintSet.connect(R.id.B, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.A, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,0);
constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

- `R.id.fragment_home_constraint_layout` is the constraint layout that contains the `ViewPager` and A.
- So I'm trying to tell "Please constrain B, which is the `ViewPager`'s item (*nota:* item = fragment) widget, to A, which is the widget of the layout which also contains the `ViewPager`".

The problem is: it does not work. No error, no crash. But it simply doesn't take effect. It's like if the constraint was not active, not set.

Why and how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Constraining two views having different parents is not possible**

> So I'm trying to tell "Please constrain B, which is the ViewPager's
>   item (nota: item = fragment) widget, to A, which is the widget of the
>   layout which also contains the ViewPager".

The above requirement wont be easy. You can still use some callbacks in your fragment. So whenever your widget in fragment chances its position, activity views should also move accordingly.

Example below should be a good start for you.

*By clicking a button in Viewpager Fragment, the widget in the activity layout changes its position.*

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonmove);
        viewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        activityButton = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_home_constraint_layout);
                ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
                set.constrainWidth(R.id.activity_button, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                set.constrainHeight(R.id.activity_button, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
                set.centerHorizontally(R.id.activity_button, R.id.fragment_home_constraint_layout);
                set.connect(R.id.activity_button, ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.vpPager, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 200);
                set.applyTo(constraintLayout);
            }
        });
    }
```

[image]           [image]